# Specify a custom DrawerNavigator header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer

I am using a DrawerNavigator and a StackNavigator

```
const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Inbox: {
      path: '/',
      screen: WelcomeContainer,
    },
    Drafts: {
      path: '/sent',
      screen: SettingsContainer,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Inbox',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    },
  }
);


const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: AppDrawer,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: false
    })
  },
  Settings: {
  screen: SettingsContainer,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
},
  About: {
  screen: About,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
}
})
```

For each element clicked on the drawer I want to show always the same header. I am using a custom header from [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/header/). I implement it in the WelcomeContainer component with this code

```
render() {
<Header
  leftComponent={<MyCustomLeftComponent />}
  centerComponent={<MyCustomCenterComponent />} 
  rightComponent={<MyCustomRightComponent />}
/>
}
```

Shall I re-write this code in every component I want to it have the header or is it possible to indicate the header in `DrawerNavigator`, and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did the following:

```
const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Inbox: {
      path: '/',
      screen: WelcomeContainer,
    },
    Drafts: {
      path: '/sent',
      screen: SettingsContainer,
    },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: { header: null }, // <--- add this
    initialRouteName: 'Inbox',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    },
  }
);

// simple HOC
const withHeader = (WrappedComponent) => { 
  return class WithHeader extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Header
            leftComponent={<MyCustomLeftComponent />}
            centerComponent={<MyCustomCenterComponent />}
            rightComponent={<MyCustomRightComponent />}
          />
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: withHeader(AppDrawer), // <------ wrap the drawer
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: false
    })
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsContainer,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: navigation.state.params.title
    })
  },
  About: {
    screen: About,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: navigation.state.params.title
    })
  }
})
```