# Problems putting a header on a DrawerNavigator in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I am trying to get a header on a DrawerNavigator in react-navigation. I have a DrawerNavigator inside a StackNavigator, and all the pages in the Drawer have a similar header (except for the title).

```
const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
    HomeRouter: { screen: HomeRouter }
  },
  {
    initialRoute: 'HomeScreen',
  });
```

`HomeRouter` is the Drawer.

```
const HomeRouter = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Agenda: { screen: Agenda },
    Nieuws: { screen: Nieuws },
    ....
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideBar,
    drawerWidth: 300,
  }
);
```

Now this gives a standard header on each of the screens in the drawer, but that is not the header I want. I want to customise it and that is difficult.
I have tried two approaches:

1. Put the header on the DrawerNavigator. I have no been able to find a way to do that. Putting navigationOptions in the screen in the StackNavigator doesn't have any effect. I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46808712 (wrapping with the `withHeader` function, but that doesn't work in react-navigation version 2. It gives an error.

**First Question: Why does this not work?**

2. Get rid of the header on HomeRouter and put headers on each of the screens in the drawer. For this to work these screens have to be wrapped inside a StackNavigator. This approach works but it requires boilerplate code in each screen, violation the DRY principle.

Basically the code becomes:

```
const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
    HomeRouter: { screen: HomeRouter,
                  navigationOptions: () => ({
                    header: null
                  })
                }
  },
  {
    initialRoute: 'HomeScreen',
  });
```

and then in the `HomeRouter`:

```
const wrap = (name, screen) => {
  return(
    createStackNavigator({
      [name]: { screen: screen }
    })
  );
};

const HomeRouter = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Agenda: { screen: wrap('Agenda', Agenda)},
    ...
```

The screens define their own header:

```
class Agenda extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = () => ({
    header: (
      <MenuHeader title="Agenda" />
    )
  });

  render() { .....
```

This solution works, but now I am trying to factor out the header code and put it in the wrapper function.

I tried to put the navigationOptions as a property on the `Agenda` screen. This works if I do it where I define the component:

```
class Agenda extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = () => ({
    header: (
      <MenuHeader title="Agenda" />
    )
  });

  render() { ...
}

Agenda.navigationOptions = () => ({
    header: (
      <MenuHeader title="Agenda" />
    )
  });

export default Agenda;
```

This solution works. But still uses boilerplate code. So I want the setting of property `navigationOptions` to the wrapper function. But then I get an error:

This code fails:

```
import Agenda from '../Pages/Agenda';

Agenda.navigationOptions = () => ({
        header: (
          <MenuHeader title="Agenda" />
        )
      });
```

This gives an error *"Invariant Violation. Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined."*

**Second Question: So why does it work when applied *before* the export, but not *after* the import? Is the imported component not the same as the exported one? I also tried it with named export/import but that does not make a difference.**